# Jquery keeping value clicked item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a survey on my site that I'm working on.

Currently, I can hover over the selection box and keep the same color after clicking on it.

### Survey.js

```
    /* Survey Cell Hover */    
    $('.survey').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('value-selected'); // add hover
        }, function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked') ){
                $(this).removeClass('value-selected'); //when radio button is clicked, hover is removed but color remains.
            }
        }
    );

    /* Survey Cell Click  */
    $('.survey').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        e.stopPropagation;
        $('.clicked:not(:hover)').removeClass('value-selected clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });
```

### Survey.css

```
        &.value-selected {
            border-color: $black;
            background-color: $lightGrey;
        }
        &.clicked{
            border-color: $black;
            background-color: $lightGrey;
        }
```

However, when I click on the second box in the survey, the color on the first box is removed.

I would like to keep the first box with the selected color unless the value of the first box is changed.

Is there a way to keep the class in the first box? I've tried doing it with `focusin` and removing `clicked` in the string from `$('.clicked:not(:hover)').removeClass('value-selected clicked');`

Any ideas of how I can do this would be appreciated.

Comment: share your  html code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to remove the selected class from the previously clicked cell then don't use the code which removes the selected class `$('.clicked:not(:hover)').removeClass('value-selected clicked');`
and use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) instead of [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add selected class.

```js
/* Survey Cell Hover */
$('.survey').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass('value-selected'); // add hover
  },
  function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
      $(this).removeClass('value-selected'); //when radio button is clicked, hover is removed but color remains.
    }
  }
);

/* Survey Cell Click  */
$('.survey').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation;
  //$('.clicked:not(:hover)').removeClass('value-selected clicked');
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
.value-selected {
  border-color: #000;
  background-color: #999;
}

.clicked {
  border-color: #000;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="survey">Survey 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="survey">Survey 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="survey">Survey 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
    $('.survey').hover(
      function() {
        $(this).addClass('value-selected');
      },
      function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
          $(this).removeClass('value-selected');
        }
      }
    );

    $('.survey').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation;
      $('.clicked:not(:hover)').removeClass('value-selected');
      $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
    });
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.survey {
  border: 2px solid cyan;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}

.value-selected {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: lightGrey;
}

.clicked {
  border-color: black;
  background-color: lightGrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="survey">Survey 1</div>
  <div class="survey">Survey 2</div>
  <div class="survey">Survey 3</div>
  <div class="survey">Survey 4</div>
</div>
```